# pyspark implement SDC2 after removing data in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

What i'm trying to do is to implement slowly changing dimension 2 to a dataframe.
The thing is that some data need to be deleted to clean the dataframe and organize the dates in correct order. Here is an exemple of the DF input (initial):

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | hash | l_open_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5070574 | 2021-09-22 | 2021-12-16 | 371f2a3a214db3027... | 2019-01-16 |
| 5070574 | 2021-12-16 | 2021-12-17 | 371f2a3a214db3027... | 2019-01-16 |
| 5070574 | 2021-12-17 | 2021-12-24 | 18391aa412a30d0e5... | 2019-01-16 |
| 5070574 | 2021-12-24 | null | 7022bc9251c847a28... | 2019-01-16 |
| 11 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-18 | d27767acd4ca4ad1e... | 2022-08-03 |
| 11 | 2021-02-18 | 2021-02-25 | d27767acd4ca4ad1e... | 2022-08-03 |
| 11 | 2021-09-22 | 2021-10-11 | d27767acd4ca4ad1e... | 2022-08-03 |
| 11 | 2021-10-11 | 2021-10-12 | d27767acd4ca4ad1e... | 2022-08-03 |
| 11 | 2021-10-12 | 2021-10-14 | d27767acd4ca4ad1e... | 2022-08-03 |
| 11 | 2022-07-12 | 2022-08-03 | d27767acd4ca4ad1e... | 2022-08-03 |
| 11 | 2022-08-03 | 2022-11-18 | d27767acd4ca4ad1e... | 2022-08-03 |
| 11 | 2022-11-18 | 2022-12-19 | 1dc8ef5249b728e76... | 2022-08-03 |
| 11 | 2022-12-19 | 2023-03-16 | 7546393b8893b97c4... | 2022-08-03 |
| 11 | 2023-02-23 | 2023-03-05 | be886ae798a439cf3... | 2022-08-03 |
| 11 | 2023-03-05 | 2023-03-16 | be886ae798a439cf3... | 2022-08-03 |
| 11 | 2023-03-16 | null | be886ae798a439cf3... | 2022-08-03 |

START/END DATE : represents the Start Date of an event and the END Date is when a new event happens and a new Start Date should appear. As for HASH: hash is a column that i created that hashes about 30 columns of data to know which row to delete

What i tried to do is to hash each line and check where there are duplicate values to delete.
In order to do that i used another column prev_hash

```
hash_df = df.withColumn(
        'previous_hash',
        lag(col('hash'), offset=1, default=None).over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("START_DATE"))
```

Then

```
hash_df = hash_df.where(
        ~col('hash').eqNullSafe(col('previous_hash'))
    )
```

Then tried to re arrange in correct order start date and end date but did not manage to do properly

What i expect to have at the end

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | l_open_date | hash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5070574 | 2021-09-22 | 2021-12-17 | 2019-01-16 | 371f2a3a214db3027... |
| 5070574 | 2021-12-17 | 2021-12-24 | 2019-01-16 | 18391aa412a30d0e5... |
| 5070574 | 2021-12-24 | null | 2019-01-16 | 7022bc9251c847a28... |
| 11 | 2021-02-01 | 2022-12-19 | 2022-08-03 | TBD |
| 11 | 2021-02-19 | 2023-03-05 | 2022-08-03 | TBD |
| 11 | 2023-03-05 | 2023-03-16 | 2022-08-03 | TBD |
| 11 | 2023-03-16 | null | 2022-08-03 | TBD |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRrYo.png)

Comment: Your question is interesting to me. However, I don't understand the START_DATE and END_DATE columns of the final output. For example, the hash `371f2a3a214db3027` has START_DATE 2021-09-22 and END_DATE 2021-12-17, while the hash `d27767acd4ca4ad1e` is between 2021-02-01 and 2022-12-19 which should be 2022-11-18 as follow to the logic of the previous example. Could you clarify more?

Comment: @LuanNguyen 
START/END DATE : represents the Start Date of an event and the END Date is when a new event happens and a new Start Date should appear.
As for HASH: hash is a column that i created that hashes about 30 columns of data to know which row to delete